# Query Custom Post Type by Tag

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wp-query, loop, tags

Kinda confused on this.. hoping someone can help.

I have custom post type named "Providers" that I want to pull entries from that are tagged "highlighted". I enabled tag support on the custom post type and then tried using tag=highlighted and tag_id=15 in a new query but it's just showing the hello world post.

Here is the gist:

https://gist.github.com/3623768

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh.. not sure why I didn't think to use tax_query. A friend figured it out. Gist is updated.

Comment: It's a best practice to post the code directly into SE rather than offload it. If the gist link changes, then this answer becomes completely irrelevant. :)